# CodeIgniter 4: Undefined type 'ModelTemplate'

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

Taking a look at Codeigniter's `model()` function shows that the function returns a `ModelTemplate` instance.

[image: CodeIgniter's model() function definition]

However, I can't seem to find the namespace for that class anywhere in CI4's core files so that I can take advantage of PHP 8.x's contructor property promotion and union typing. Even IDE's Intelliphense can't find it.

Take a look at this code:

```
use App\Models\OpenAILangModel;
use <Where>\<Is>\ModelTemplate; // Can't find the correct namespace for this class

class TrainintData() {
   // constructor
   function __construct(protected ModelTemplate | null $trainingDataModel) {
      $this->trainingDataModel = model(OpenAILangModel::class);
      ...
   }
}
```

Thus:

> Use of unknown class:
> 'App\Controllers\ModelTemplate'PHP(PHP0413)
> Use of unknown> class: 'App\Controllers\ModelTemplate'PHP(PHP0413)
> Undefined type 'ModelTemplate'.intelephense(P1009)

Here's another use case:

```
public function getTainingModelInstance() : ModelTemplate {
   return model(OpenAILangModel::class); // Too concrete but just to demonstrate what I'm trying to accomplish here
}
```

Anybody here enountered this same problem?

Comment: If you don't know where it's declared - how do you know you can use it like you're using it? What you know about it at all?

Comment: "model() function shows that the function returns" --- what is the relationship between a `model()` function and a `$model` variable and a `$this->model` property?

Comment: @zerkms I updated my question to show what CI4's model() core function declaration looks like.

Comment: https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/d72a893a7519a2022138ce69e698bee479d86c02/system/Common.php#L804

Comment: See the link to source code, it's a generic template. Effectively it's a subclass of `CodeIgniter\Model`.

Comment: @zerkms thanks for pointing it out. Any recommendations on how I cann address this on the variable typing or use namespace?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question as it's not clear what you're doing: you have `$this->model = model(...);` and you also have independent `$model` variable. And there is no connection between them.

Comment: I renamed $model to $trainingDataModel to avoid the confusion.

Comment: The question is still the same - your `$trainingDataModel` is unused in your shared code.

Comment: In your second case - return type is simply `OpenAILangModel`.